# Linq - How to get types participating in expression

Tags: c#, linq

How can I get all types participating in a linq expression? I actually need this to be able to cache the query results.

In this example it is easy:

```
var Query = (from x in DataContext.Current.ContractDurations select x);
```

as 
   the type i need is provided in

```
Query.ElementType
```

But what happens when I do this:

```
var Query = (from x in DataContext.Current.ContractDurations select x.ID);
```

The ElementType will be int. The same problem will exist with joins where the ElementType will be some random anonymous type.

Comment: hi Not complete understanding what you mean. What would you like the second statement to return

Comment: Are you saying you want to get the type of x in both cases? If so, i think you will need to `walk the expression tree` (search in google)

Comment: Are you trying to get the query element type, or all types involved in the query? It's not very clear from your question

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get all types involved in the query.

Comment: And `walk the expression tree` did not produce anything usefull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public class QueryExpressionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public List<Type> Types
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }


    public QueryExpressionVisitor()
    {
        Types = new List<Type>();

    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return base.Visit(node);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Type.IsGenericTypeDefinition && node.Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IQueryable<>))
            CheckType(node.Type.GetGenericArguments()[0]);
        return base.VisitConstant(node);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        CheckType(node.Member.DeclaringType);
        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }



    private void CheckType(Type t)
    {
        if (!Types.Contains(t))
        {
            Types.Add(t);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing a problem here... As long as the original data context is IQueryable, you should have access to ElementType.

See the following:

```
void Main()
{
    List<Alerts> alerts = new List<Alerts>();
    alerts.Add(new Alerts(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)));
    alerts.Add(new Alerts(DateTime.Now));

    IQueryable<Alerts> qAlerts = alerts.AsQueryable();

    var query1 = qAlerts.Select (a => a.Begins);
    Console.WriteLine(query1.ElementType);

    var query2 = qAlerts.Select (a => a);
    Console.WriteLine(query2.ElementType);

    var query3 = alerts.Select (a => a);
    Console.WriteLine(query3.AsQueryable().ElementType);
}
public class Alerts
{
    public DateTime Begins {get; set;}
    public Alerts(DateTime begins)
    {
        Begins = begins;
    }
}
```

The key is that ElementType is a member of IQueryable, so you need to make sure that EITHER the original source is IQueryable (as in query1 and query2), OR that you cast the query to IQueryable (as in query3).

Finally, for this kind of thing, grab a copy of LinqPad... The free version is great, the paid version will give you intellisense.

Comment: I think I am not getting through here. Probably havent explained this correctly. The problem with 'ElementType' is that it points to the return type of the IQueriable. So for example, if a query has a bunch of joins and finally selects an int I will get Int32 in the ElementType which is not what I want. What I want is to know **all** the types that participate in the query so I can then filter out which of them are dataobjects (entities) in order be able to add cache dependencies on those types.